# How to get attribute from a list of partition keys in DynamoDB - is scan my only option?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've got a list of partition keys from one table.

```
userId["123","456","235"]
```

I need to get an attribute that they all share. like "username".

What would be the best practice to get them all at once?

Is scan my only option knowing that I know all my partition keys?

> Do I know the sort key? yes but only the beginning of it. Therefore I
>   don't think I could use batchGetItem.

Answer (score 1):

Scan is only appropriate if you don't know the partition keys. Because you know the partition keys you want to search, you can achieve the desired behavior with multiple [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) operations.

A Query searches all documents with the specified partition key; you can only query one partition key per request, so you'll need multiple queries, but this will still be significantly more efficient than a single Scan operation.

If you're only looking for documents with a sort key that begins with something, you can include it in your `KeyConditionExpression` along with the partition key.

For example, if you wanted to only return documents whose sort key begins with a certain string, you could pass something like `userId = :user_id AND begins_with(#SortKey, :str)` as the key condition expression.

Comment: Thanks Collin, but wouldn't multiple queries be more expensive to run than just doing one scan?

Comment: No it won’t. A query only consumes RCU for items that match the key condition. Scan consumes RCU for everything in your table (or until you stop scanning).

Comment: In this, how would I return the `lastEvaluatedKey` to the client? Multiple queries will have multiple lastEvaluatedKeys. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently achieve the result by using [PartQL SELECT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html) statement. It allows to query array of partition keys with IN operator and apply additional conditions on other attributes without causing a full table scan.

> To ensure that a SELECT statement does not result in a full table
> scan, the WHERE clause condition must specify a partition key. Use the
> equality or IN operator.